# .htaccess remove a part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My magento website has paths like this

```
https://www.test.com/manufacturer-bourgeat.html
```

But i need to remove **manufacturer-** part when user goes to that kind of pages. like

```
https://www.test.com/bourgeat.html
```

I used this *.htaccess* code for do that but it didn't worked

```
RewriteRule ^manufacturer-(.*)$ $1
```

Anyone know how to do that please, Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure why someone vote for close the question

Comment: You'll need the `R` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive.

Answer (score 1):

have you switched on the rewrite?

try 
**RewriteEngine on**
before the Rewrite rule

correct-> 
RewriteRule    ^bourgeat.html/?$    manufacturer-bourgeat.html

for more clarity please have a look at https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners

Comment: Yes it's a magento site, so it has RewriteEngine on already on htaccess file